# Obtengo error intentado usar el modulo "flask mysql" en Mac

Tags: python-3.x, flask

He instalado flask-mysql con pip3. Sin mensaje de error. Por si fuera un problema de lugar de instalación he corrido el comando pip3 install flask-mysql

- Desde Terminal en mi directorio raíz
- Desde la consola que ofrece PyCharm en el directorio del proyecto que tengo abierto. Que me constesta que ya están los recursos disponibles

> "MacBook-Pro-3:moocwebapp elfulio$ pip3 install flask-mysql
>
> Requirement already satisfied: flask-mysql in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.5.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: Flask in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask-mysql) (1.1.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: PyMySQL in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from flask-mysql) (0.10.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-mysql) (1.1.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-mysql) (1.0.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-mysql) (2.11.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-mysql) (7.1.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask->flask-mysql) (1.1.1)"

Sin embargo a la hora de llamar al modulo desde el servidor Python según diferentes combinaciones que he ido encontrando por foros solo obtengo. mensajes de error:

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
```

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb'*

```
from flask-mysqldb import MySQL
```

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mysql'*

```
from flask-mysql import MySQL
```

*SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
```

Esta combinación es de la página https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#

He probado desinstalar y volver a instalar el modulo, lo hace sin problema, pero luego sigo siendo incapaz de incorporarlo al servidor.

```
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
import os.path

app = Flask(__name__)
```

Alguna orientación?
Gracias

Comment: No te metas a la carpeta de tu proyecto, ejecuta `pip3 install flask-mysql` desde tu directorio de *home*, es decir el directorio que te ubica apenas abres la terminal.

Comment: Hola Gabi. Tambien lo he hecho desde mi directorio raiz

Comment: Disculpa que le dí al enter muy rapido. Lo he desinstalado y vuelto a instalar pero sigue igual. Muchas gracias